# Pandas `.to_pydatetime()` not working inside a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have strings like `'03-21-2019'` that I want to convert to the native Python datetime object: that is, of the `datetime.datetime` type. The conversion is easy enough through `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

date_str = '03-21-2019'
pd_Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(date_str)
py_datetime_object = pd_Timestamp.to_pydatetime()
print(type(py_datetime_object))
```

with the result

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

This is precisely what I want, since I want to compute `timedelta`'s by subtracting one of these from another - perfectly well-defined in the native Python `datetime.datetime` class. However, my data is in a `pd.DataFrame`. When I try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
df.loc[0] = ['03-21-2019']
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:
                              pd.to_datetime(x).to_pydatetime())
print(type(df['Date'].iloc[0]))
```

the result is

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

This is the ***WRONG*** type, and I can't for the life of me figure out why only part of the `lambda` expression is getting evaluated (that is, string-to-pandas-Timestamp), and not the last part (that is, pandas-Timestamp-to-datetime.datetime). It doesn't work if I define the function explicitly, either, instead of using a `lambda` expression:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def to_native_datetime(date_str: str) -> dt.datetime:
    return pd.to_datetime(date_str).to_pydatetime()


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
df.loc[0] = ['03-21-2019']
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(to_native_datetime)
print(type(df['Date'].iloc[0]))
```

The result is the same as before. It's definitely doing part of the function, as the result is not a string anymore. But I want the native Python `datetime.datetime` object, and I see no way of getting it. This looks like a bug in `pandas`, but I'm certainly willing to see it as user error on my part.

> Why can't I get the native `datetime.datetime` object out of a `pandas.DataFrame` string column?

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377123/pandas-to-datetime-not-working) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates), but neither of them answer my question.

[EDIT]: Here's something even more bizarre:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


def to_native_datetime(date_str: str) -> dt.datetime:
    return dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
df.loc[0] = ['03-21-2019']
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(to_native_datetime)
print(type(df['Date'].iloc[0]))
```

Here I'm not even using `pandas` to convert the string, and I ***STILL*** get a

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

out of it!

Many thanks for your time!

[FURTHER EDIT]: Apparently, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278042/storing-pure-python-datetime-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe), in Nehal J Wani's answer, it comes out that `pandas` automatically converts back to its native datetime format when you assign into a `pd.DataFrame`. This is not what I wanted to hear, but apparently, I'm going to have to convert on-the-fly when I read out of the `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Weirdly the pandas object index will maintain the datetime.datetime object but not a Series or column in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the [Sarah Messer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897136/7556397)’s answer and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61999655/7556397), I could solve the problem by reassigning the array back to the dataframe and forcing its dtype to object:

```
arr_date = df['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
df['Date']= pd.Series(arr_date, dtype=object)
```

example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [datetime(2021, 8, 28, 4, 10), datetime(2021, 8, 28, 4, 10)]})
df.dtypes

#   date    datetime64[ns]
#   dtype: object

arr_date = df["date"].dt.to_pydatetime()
df["date"] = pd.Series(arr_date, dtype="object")
df.dtypes

#   date    object
#   dtype: object

df.iloc[0,0]

# datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 28, 4, 10)
```

Comment: Be aware that if indices of df are not starting with 0, the dates resulting from pd.Series(arr_date, dtype="object") will be shifted automatically by pandas. Use reset_index when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your actual goal is, you've a couple options you didn't mention directly.

1) If you have a static datetime object or a column of (pandas) Timestamps, and you're willing to deal with the Pandas version of a Timedelta (`pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta`), you can do the subtraction directly in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date'])
df.loc[0] = [pd.to_datetime('03-21-2019')]
df.loc[:, 'Offset'] = pd.Series([datetime.now()])
df.loc[:, 'Diff1'] = df['Offset'] - df['Date']
df.loc[:, 'Diff2'] = df['Date'] - datetime.now()
```

2) If you don't care about Dataframes, but are willing to deal with lists / numpy arrays, you can convert the datetimes to python-native datetimes by operating on the series rather than on individual elements. Below, `arr` is a `numpy.ndarray` of `datetime.datetime` objects. You can change it to a regular list of datetime with `list(arr)`:

```
arr = df['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```