# Filtering values in Dataframe based on two Dates

Tags: python

My dataframe looks like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBLWl.png)

I am trying to select the values between two months. I have already calculated a while loop which selects the start of the month and the end of the month

```
start_date = date(2014, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 12, 1)

while start_date <= end_date:
    end_of_month = start_date + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)

    print (start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print (end_of_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))    

    start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

I always got an error message and so i wanted to try if i can select dates without the loop:

```
start_date = date(2014, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 12, 1)
Portfolio.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

I always get the error message `KeyError: datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)`, but i don't know why?
Even if i only wanter to filter a single Date: `Portfolio.loc[start_date]`

Comment: Try printing `type(Portfolio.index[0])` and `type(date(2014, 1, 1))`. If they are different, then you need to convert one of them to the other one type.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Indeed, my index is a different type. I tried to convert it using pd.to_datetime, but i need `datetime.date`. But this turns my index into `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` Do you know how to convert it to a `Datetime.date` object?

Comment: Try using the method explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593741/pandas-to-pydatetime-not-working-inside-a-dataframe) and let me know if it works.

Comment: I did a little work around: `Portfolio['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(Portfolio['Date'])
Portfolio = Portfolio.set_index('Datetime')` and this workes fine now