# Pandas to_datetime no error on wrong format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I read in a CSV file containing dates.  Some dates may be formatted wrong and I want to find those.  With the following approach I would **expect the 2nd row to be `NaT`**.  But pandas seems to ignore the specified format no matter if I set `infer_datetime_format` or `exact`.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

DATA = StringIO("""date
2019 10 07
   2018 10
""")
df = pd.read_csv(DATA)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y %m %d", errors='coerce', exact=True)
```

results in

```
        date
0 2019-10-07
1 2018-10-01
```

The [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) documentation refers to [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) but when I test it with plain Python it works:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('  2018 10', '%Y %m %d')
```

I get the expected value error:

```
ValueError: time data '  2018 10' does not match format '%Y %m %d'
```

What do I miss?

FYI: This question [pandas to_datetime not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377123/pandas-to-datetime-not-working) seems to be related but is different and it seems to be fixed by now.  It is working with my pandas version 0.25.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, see [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12649) for details.

Since we needed a solution I came up with the following workaround. Please note that in my question I used `read_csv` to keep the reproducible code snippet small and simple.  We actually use `read_fwf` and here is some sample data (time.txt):

```
2019 10 07 + 14:45 15:00  # Foo
2019 10 07 + 18:00 18:30  # Bar
  2019 10 09 + 13:00 13:45  # Wrong indentation
```

I felt stating the row number is also a good idea so I added a little bit more voodoo:

```
class FileSanitizer(io.TextIOBase):
    row = 0
    date_range = None

    def __init__(self, iterable, date_range):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.date_range = date_range

    def readline(self):
        result = next(self.iterable)
        self.row += 1
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(result[self.date_range[0]:self.date_range[1]], "%Y %m %d")
        except ValueError as excep:
            raise ValueError(f'row: {self.row} => {str(excep)}') from ValueError
        return result


filepath = 'time.txt'
colspecs = [[0, 10], [13, 18], [19, 25], [26, None]]
names = ['date', 'start', 'end', 'description']

with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    df = pd.read_fwf(FileSanitizer(file, colspecs[0]),
                     colspecs=colspecs,
                     names=names,
                     )
```

The solution is based on this answer [How to skip blank lines with read_fwf in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584515/2606766). Please note this will **not** work with `read_csv`.

Now I get the following error as expected:

```
ValueError: row: 3 => time data '  2019 10 ' does not match format '%Y %m %d'
```

If anyone has a more sophisticated answer I'm happy to learn.